# [HTML / JavaScript]:

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML file, I have a JavaScript function named "CheckCaptcha". I am using following code line to execute that function when an image is clicked. It is not working. After hours of tweaking and modifying the code, it is not simply reaching to the location where the JavaScript function lies.

I am using this code line:

`<input type="image" src="images/join.gif"  name="SubmitStudent" onclick="CheckCaptcha();" width="98" height="31"/>`

The JavaScript section is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckCaptcha()
{
    aler("-");
    var CaptchaWord;
    CaptchaWord = document.getElementById(StudentCaptchaImage);
    alert(CaptchaWord);
    if (CaptchaWord.length <= 4)
    {
        alert("Please enter words as seen in the image.");
        return false;
    }   
}   
</Script>
```

Actually, I am a new user, and StackOverflow is avoiding me to post the entire HTML section.

Comment: Can you post the script part?

Comment: That's a perfectly valid JavaScript call, as long as the function is in scope. Are you sure that the function is available from that "location", or is it included inside another object?

Comment: Welcome. You can post the HTML as code - paste it, and click on the `Code` button - 101010.

Comment: you forgot the `t` in `alert`

Comment: Oh Freak, when I submitted the entire HTML code, it looks horrible. Please ignore it in my answer posted below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function CheckCaptcha()
{
    alert("-");
    var CaptchaWord = document.getElementById('StudentCaptchaImage');
    alert(CaptchaWord);
    if (CaptchaWord.value.length <= 4)
    {
        alert("Please enter words as seen in the image.");
        return false;
    }   
}
```

- the `.value` attribute contains the value, the DOM element does not have a `length` property.
- the gEBI method takes a string, not an identifier as you had it.. unless it was a variable.
- your example had a typo in the first alert, I'm guessing you recently added it and it was not the initial problem.

If you're not sure of anything you should start alerting as many things as possible..

```
alert( typeof CaptchaWord.length )
```

Comment: I was using double quotes within getElementByID, whereas a single quote is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `getElementById` takes a string:

```
CaptchaWord = document.getElementById("StudentCaptchaImage");
```

Comment: your DOM element doesn't have a `length` property - try mine if this doesn't fully do it.

Answer (score 1):

Have checked for any errors in JavaScript  which may not be related to this particular function? Use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) to find any errors 
I tried following code and its working

```
<script>
    function CheckCaptcha(){
        alert("test");
    }
</script>
<input type="image" src="images/join.gif" name="SubmitStudent" onclick="CheckCaptcha();" width="98" height="31"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning false to cancel the event bubble?

```
onclick="CheckCaptcha(); return false"
```